# Exported .dae file has no image references

Tags: export, collada

I created simple object with 2 textures and wanted to export it as Collada .dae file.

After export I found out that the node in the .dae for image references is completely empty like this + there are no images being exported with the file either (I have checked "Copy" under Texture Options for Collada file export):

```
<library_images/>
```

I am using Blender v3.6.4 on Win10 x64.

This is my test file:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann no, it does not, as I said I have COPY checked in texture options for the Collada export

Comment: Having never used that exporter, I don't know whether [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/collada.html#texture-options) section in the Blender manual helps?

Comment: @JohnEason no, it did not help: the only image option there-COPY checkbox under texture options - I already used by default...IDK but I am starting to think that this might big a bug in the 3.6 version.